# Running Android Emulator on Azure VM

Tags: android-emulator, azure-vm

I have been trying to run an Android Emulator on a Windows Azure VM.
The VM is a Standard D4s v3 (4 vcpus, 16 GiB memory) running Windows Server 2016, so it
should support nested virtualization.

I have installed and configured the following:

- Android SDK, version 30.1.5.0
- Hardware acceleration:
- Intel HAXM 7.6.1
- Tested Android versions: 7.0, 7.1, 8.0, 8.1, 9.0, 10.0
- GPU mode used: swiftshader_indirect

I keep getting an exception popup regarding the GPU as follows:

```
GPU #1
Make: 1414
Model: Microsoft Basic Render Driver

Some users have experienced emulator stability issues with this driver version.
As a result we're selecting a compatability render.
```

Is it possible to run an Android Emulator on a Windows Azure VM?

Comment: Hi Ricky, did you ever find a solution for this ? I am facing exactly the same issue.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76903618/how-do-i-run-android-virtual-device-in-azure-vm

Comment: Hi @Stanza, I never found a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/android?view=azure-devops#test-on-the-android-emulator) from Microsoft, Android Emulator only runs on the Hosted macOS agent.